# Cannot see review history per user in /review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I can not access a single person's review history using the below URL (replacing `<id>` with a User ID):

```
https://askubuntu.com/review/close/history?userId=<id>
```

[(Try me, against Kaz Wolfe's profile)](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/history?userId=208574)

But, I can access someone's (global) review history using the profile URL:

```
https://askubuntu.com/users/<id>/<user-slug>?tab=activity&sort=reviews
```

[(Try me, against Kaz Wolfe's profile)](https://askubuntu.com/users/208574/kaz-wolfe?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

---

Upon attempting to use the former against my profile, you're given your own user review history, not mine (like expected). Is there a reason for this, or is this just a bug?

If there *is* a reason for this, why can users still access review histories though the profile page but not `/review`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only moderators have access to this particular filter; 10K users can view all reviews (except for skipped) for a given queue and their own reviews for a given queue (optionally including skipped).

The purpose of the per-user filter (which was originally moderator-only) was to allow folks to, uh, review *their own* reviews.

See: [Can our Review History also list the items we have skipped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221134/can-our-review-history-also-list-the-items-we-have-skipped/234909#234909)

Comment: When a non-moderator specifies a userId other than their own, it seems to me that it would be best either to *redirect* to the URL with their own userId or to show the user an error message (or some kind of special message), rather than showing the user their own review history at the URL for someone else's. Unless the current surprising behavior is necessary, it seems to me there really is a bug here.

Comment: With @EliahKagan's argument in mind, it's also the question that we already *can* see everyone's review history through their userpage, so I'm still not sure why we can't use `/review` for the same thing.

Comment: It's just not something the tool was ever designed for, @Kaz. To the best of my knowledge, we don't actually publish any *links* to such URLs anywhere for non-moderators (mods have reports that include them); so the only way to get such a URL is to compose it manually - and there's never any guarantee that an unpublished URL will do anything useful, even if it looks sane.